# UserForm to update Database based upon textbox

Tags: database, excel, userform, vba

I am trying to have an input for an employee ID. Once entered and the command button pressed, it will auto populate the userform with the current data listed in the database. Then  the user has the ability to change any of the inputs and then "submit" the form which will paste back over in the database. I have searched around and found some code that should work for what I want to do but I am just struggling to understand how to adapt it to my specific needs.

```
    Option Explicit
Public frmName As Variant 'store row of name
Public frmDate As Variant 'store column of date

'Subroutine when clicking the first ("find") button
Private Sub btnfind_Click()
'Defining variables
Dim pr01 As String
Dim dt01 As Date
Dim tsk01 As Integer

'Assigning variables to inputs
pr01 = UserForm1.TextBox1.Text
dt01 = UserForm1.TextBox2.Text
tsk01 = UserForm1.TextBox3.Text

'Looking for Name in column "A"
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet4")
    frmName = .Columns("A").Find(pr01).Row
End With


'Looking for inut Date in row "1"
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet4")
    frmDate = .Rows(1).Find(CDate(dt01)).Column
End With

If frmName Is Nothing Or frmDate Is Nothing Then
    'not found
    Exit Sub
  End If

'Retrieving the existing number of tasks according to name and date
'and showing number in the 'tasks' text input box in the user form
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet4")
    UserForm1.TextBox3.Text = .Cells(frmName, frmDate)
End With

End Sub

'Subroutine when clicking the Second ("update") button
Private Sub btnupdate_Click()

'Paste updated Number of tasks in appropriate cells according to name and date
'The new number of tasks should over write what was there previously
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet4")
    .Cells(frmName, frmDate) = UserForm1.TextBox3.Text
End With
End Sub
```

Is the frmName and frmDate the name of two of the textboxes? Any help in understanding this code to apply to my spreadsheet would be extremely appreciated.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

"frmXxxxx" normally means Xxxxx is a user form.  Here lines 2 and 3 of the code declare frmName and frmDate as `Variant`s and the comments say they are for a row and a column.  These are really unhelpful names.

Normally the variables to hold a row or a column would be declared as `Long`.  They have to be declared as `Variant`s because of the shoddy code that uses them.

Consider:

```
'Looking for Name in column "A"
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet4")
  frmName = .Columns("A").Find(pr01).Row
End With
```

and

```
If frmName Is Nothing Or frmDate Is Nothing Then
  'not found
  Exit Sub
End If
```

Variable `pr01` has been set to `UserForm1.TextBox1.Text`.  From the comments I assume this text box is for the user to enter a name.  It would have been helpful if the text box and the variable were given meaningful names.

If the name in `pr01` cannot be found in column A then the `Find` will return `Nothing`.   This is why `frmName` was defined as a `Variant` because a `Long` cannot be set to `Nothing`.

While this will work it is hardly user-friendly or maintainer-friendly code.

Apart from the dreadful names, I would suggest something like:

```
Public frmName As Long      'store row of name
Dim rng as Range        ' Temporary variable

'Looking for Name in column "A"
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet4")

  Set rng = .Columns("A").Find(pr01)
  If rng Is Nothing Then
    ' Tell user the name could not be found
    :   :
    Exit Sub
  Endif
  frmName = rng.Row      

End With
```

I hope the above helps you decipher this code.  I also hope my code is easier to understand.